# MobX Setting of observables error - cannot read property filter of undefined

Tags: javascript, state, observable, mobx

I encountered this error as I'm implementing preloading features via MobX. When I try to set observable in my mobx store, this error occures.

[image: MobX Error - setting observables]

My store looks like this

```
import {observable} from 'mobx'

class UI {
  @observable preloading


  constructor() {
    this.preloading = false
  }


  startPreloading() {
    this.preloading = true    // <-- this triggers the error
  }

  stopPreloading() {
    this.preloading = false
  }
}
```

As the error points deep into MobX source code, I struggle to debug it. Especially since this is very basic MobX and it's hard to get it wrong.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: [**It works for me**](http://jsbin.com/kazopixape/1/edit?js,console). Try writing `ui.startPreloading()` in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a regression introduced in the yesterday release of Redux DevTools Extension. Please update the extension to `2.14.1` from Chrome Store to get it fixed.

Comment: Great! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

So the problem wasn't with MobX itself. It was something with mobx-remotedev. That is a library that unlocks redux devtools to mobx code. I implemented it like...

```
import remotedev from 'mobx-remotedev'

class UI {
  //
  // store stuff
  //
}


export default remotedev(UI)
```

Don't know what exactly it was tho. I submited an issue on creators Github, so here is the link, in case it gets resolved https://github.com/zalmoxisus/mobx-remotedev/issues/19